# Add image size if page template

Tags: functions, images

I'm building a members website with WordPress Multisite. Is it possible to restrict how many images are being generated depending on the selected template?

I have tried the following lines of code to generate certain images on the gallery template:

```
// Generate on all uploads
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
set_post_thumbnail_size( 1440, 350, true ); 
add_image_size( 'standard_box', 450, 215, true );
add_image_size( 'default_image', 691, 9999 );

// Generate on gallery template only
if ( is_page_template('page-gallery.php') ) {
add_image_size( 'gallery', 900, 9999 );
add_image_size( 'gallery_thumb', 450, 450, true );
}
```

This hasn't worked. I've done some research and can't seem to find anything on the subject. If you could point me in the right direction, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: There is also Otto's [Dynamic Image Resizer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/dynamic-image-resizer/) which lets you define as many image sizes as you want, but only generates an image at a particular size when it is needed. SO for your example the gallery thumbnails would only be generated for the images that appear on the page-gallery.php template.

Comment: Just want to mention other two great options: @kaiser's [Dynamic Image Resize](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Dynamic-Image-Resize) and the [Photon service](http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/photon/) in JetPack.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This has always been a bugbear for me - the lack of on-demand image sizing, and the subsequent number of files you can end up with if you have lots of sizes!

I can see the logic behind your efforts - the trouble is, `add_image_size` only truly comes into play at point-of-upload. As such, `is_page_template(..)` will always be `false`.

A quick [google](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=wordpress%20image%20resize%20on%20the%20fly) dug up [Aqua Resizer](http://www.wpexplorer.com/resize-wordpress-images-on-the-fly-with-aqua-resizer/), a script designed to tackle this issue. Rather than use `add_image_size`, you use `aq_resize` directly in your theme, and if a size for the image doesn't exist, it's created and cached on-the-fly.

In fact I've used a similar, albeit different, technique on several sites with many image sizes. You still save the overhead of WordPress generating *every* size for *every* image uploaded - they're generated on-the-fly (& cached) as and when they're requested. Where it differs, is that you can simply use all of WP's standard image functions and template tags as you would normally!

Also, as @Waqas mentioned, using Aqua Resizer will leave orphaned files when you delete an image from your media library. With my technique, *all* files will be deleted, since they're saved to the database & recognised by WordPress.

```
/**
 * Resize internally-registered image sizes on-demand.
 *
 * @link    http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/139624/1685
 * 
 * @param   mixed   $null
 * @param   int     $id
 * @param   mixed   $size
 * @return  mixed
 */
function wpse_139624_image_downsize( $null, $id, $size ) {
    static $sizes = array(
        'post-thumbnail' => array(
            'height' => 350,
            'width'  => 1440,
            'crop'   => true,
        ),

        'standard_box' => array(
            'height' => 215,
            'width'  => 450,
            'crop'   => true,
        ),

        'default_image' => array(
            'height' => 9999,
            'width'  => 691,
            'crop'   => false,
        ),

        'gallery' => array(
            'height' => 900,
            'width'  => 9999,
            'crop'   => false,
        ),

        'gallery_thumb' => array(
            'height' => 450,
            'width'  => 450,
            'crop'   => true,
        ),
    );

    if ( ! is_string( $size ) || ! isset( $sizes[ $size ] ) )
        return $null;
    if ( ! is_array( $data = wp_get_attachment_metadata( $id ) ) )
        return $null;
    if ( ! empty( $data['sizes'][ $size ] ) )
        return $null;
    if ( $data['height'] <= $sizes[ $size ]['height'] && $data['width'] <= $sizes[ $size ]['width'] )
        return $null;
    if ( ! $file = get_attached_file( $id ) )
        return $null;

    $editor = wp_get_image_editor( $file );

    if ( ! is_wp_error( $editor ) ) {
        $data['sizes'] += $editor->multi_resize(
            array(
                $size => $sizes[ $size ],
            )
        );

        wp_update_attachment_metadata( $id, $data );
    }

    return $null;
}

add_filter( 'image_downsize', 'wpse_139624_image_downsize', 10, 3 );
```

And in practice:

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $id, 'gallery' ); // Resized if not already
wp_get_attachment_image_src( $id, 'standard_box' ); // Resized if not already
the_post_thumbnail(); // You get the idea!
// And so forth!
```

I'm intending to turn this into a plugin that will automatically convert all `add_image_size` calls into on-demand resizing, so watch this space!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to leave such a great answer. I'll certainly give this a go. It's important I get this right before opening my server up to multiple users. I'll give you a shout if I have any further questions.

Comment: I gave this a go with the_post_thumbnail(); and it works perfectly. One problem: When I delete the image, it leaves behind the one which has been re-sized by your script. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

---

**Disclaimer:**
  - This *isn't* actually an answer.
  - It *is* intended to help you with your additional research on the topic.
  - Furthermore it *is* reflecting a - at least felt - lately more frequent occurrence of similar questions regarding similar problems.

---

Additional information regarding this topic on Wordpress Development:

- [Removing Image Sizes for Custom Post Type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/131497/22534)
- [Differentiate Featured Image from Post Images upon Upload](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/135464/22534)
- [Image quality based on image size](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/138751/22534)
- [Generate fixed image sizes for different pages, eliminate sizes during upload](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/131849/22534)
- [How to Dynamically Resize WordPress Image On-The-Fly (custom field/theme option)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/35055/22534)
- [Resizing only featured images while uploading](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/106463/22534)
- [How to generate thumbnails when needed only?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/53344/22534)
- [How do I delete all generated images from my server except those currently used in posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/135969/22534)

*Note:* The list isn't ordered and comprehensive by any means.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to create thumbs on the fly you can use [Aqua image resizer](https://github.com/syamilmj/Aqua-Resizer/), But there is a drawback of this mini script. The created thumbs will not delete upon deleting image from library. But its not a big deal. If required you can do so via [SHH commands](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2012/05/remove-image-sizes.html)

Comment: Good point about files not being deleted. My solution won't suffer from this! (see updated answer).

Answer (score 1):

It is not a direct answer for your problem. But I will help you to make image according to your need.

When you use add_image_size it does not resize the existing images. it only works for the new images that will be uploaded after adding your add_image_size function.

So your code will not generate new images for is_page_template function.

But you can use a simple php class to solve your problem.... it is a famous php class that is being used for a lot of premium theme out there for WordPress. It is called Aqua-Resizer.

You can find more details here https://github.com/syamilmj/Aqua-Resizer
Wiki: https://github.com/syamilmj/Aqua-Resizer/wiki

**Problem that may arise:**

This function works this way....

```
<?php aq_resize( $url, $width, $height, $crop, $single ) ?>
```

So when it can not crop ( for small image that your height or width defined ) it does not show anything. You can overcome this situation by checking whether your are getting a null value after passing the url within this function very easily like mine here....

```
<?php 
$thumb = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full' ); if($thumb){ $url = aq_resize( $thumb, 400, 200, true, true ); if(!$url){ $url = WPM_DIR.'/assets/images/demo/wrong_image_size.jpg'; } }else{ $url = WPM_DIR.'/assets/images/demo/400x200_no_feature_image.jpg'; } 
?>
```

In this way you can ensure that the specific image will be generated for specific page template and this way your website will be much more cleaner.

P.S: this php class usages WordPress core cropping system so there is not security issues.